# algebraic and topological K-theory of generalized flag manifolds

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-k-theory, flag-varieties

In the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9912153v1.pdf, the authors give the definition of "flag-like" varieties (Definition 5, pag. 13). They justify the choice of the name by saying (but not proving) that any generalized flag variety $X:=G/P$ (with $G$ reductive and $P$ a parabolic subgroup) is an example of "flag-like" in their sense. In particular, it follows that their algebraic and topological K-theories coincide: the natural forgetful morphism 
$$K^0_{alg}(X)\to K^0_{top}(X)$$ is an *isomorphism*. I have two questions:

1) Do you know where I can find a proof of this isomorphism property of generalized flag manifolds? It seems that for the authors it is a well-known result, but I'm not able to find it in literature.

2) What is known in general about the class of smooth projective varieties for which the forgetful morphism above is an isomorphism? Is there any paper in which it is studied? The class of flag-like varieties introduced in the cited paper is just a proper subclass.